# Javascript: parent.frmMain.hidChgType.value = "1"

Tags: javascript

```
if (lVarScript == 'CN_TYPE')
        {
            parent.fnEffDateCheck();        
            document.frmMain.hidChgType.value   = '1';
            parent.fnChangeType();
        }
```

wat doest the above code means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check the variable '**lVarScript**' equal to '**CN_TYPE**'

   If yes
2. Call a function **fnEffDateCheck** in parent. [ *parent*: Returns a reference to the parent of the current window or subframe. ]
3. Change the value of DOM element **hidChgType** in the form '**frmMain**' to 1.
4. Call another function **fnChangeType** in parent.

Answer (score 0):

Ordinary code that sets value in field hidChgType of form frmMain to 1 if lVarScript is equals to CN_TYPE.